# Change the tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags

I have a contenteditable div. How can the user change the tags inside, from p to h1? (and the way round if he changes his mind) Of course, the user must be able to choose what parts are h1 and what parts are p.

Something similar to what we have here in StackOverflow when we make a question: we select a word, click  to B and we make it black. I want the user choose a sentence they want and make it a h1.

I suppose the user has to select the sentence or put the cursor there and then click the button, to make the change. The question is how can I know what sentence or paragraph the user want to change?

Here I have the code to play and check: [http://jsfiddle.net/d9z5r49j/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/d9z5r49j/)

HTML:

```
<div id='ToP'>p</div>
<div id='ToH'>h1</div>

<div contenteditable>
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#ToH").click(function() {

     //this changes all the p. How to change only what the user chooses?
     //$("p")).replaceWith('<h1>' + this.html() + '</h1>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could something like this

ok updated answer

```
<input id="changeH1" type="button" value="H1" />
<input id="changeP" type="button" value="p" />
<div contenteditable>
    <p>first paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
<br />
<script>
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
        }

        var nNd = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nNd);
        return nNd.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return document.selection.createRange();
        } else {
            return getSelection();
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('#changeH1').click( function() { 
        if($('span').length > 0 )
            $('span').remove();           
        var mytext = selectHTML();            
        if(mytext)
            $('span').parent().replaceWith($('<h1>' +  $("span").parent().text() + '</h1>'))
    });

    $('#changeP').click( function() {
        if($('span').length > 0 )
            $('span').remove();
        var mytext = selectHTML();            
        if(mytext)
        $('span').parent().replaceWith($('<p>' +  $("span").parent().text() + '</p>'))
    });
});
</script>
```

now just mark the element you want to change and hit the button.
here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/d9z5r49j/9/

Comment: Please check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9z5r49j/ Be aware that in my code I use $(selector) as an example. In fact I do not know what to use there. That is the question.

Comment: target the class or the id you want ex `<p class="something">`

Comment: That is the point: the user is the one that must choose the target

Comment: there is still a problem after you clicked your first element if you click again it breaks down give a sec to fix it.

Comment: @Nrc ok this is working now you just have to mark a part of your text and click the button you want

Comment: When you select to convert to p It deletes words. It I just put the cursor, it does not work. But more or less it works. It is useful to have an idea

Comment: do you add the updated answer i changed the `if($('span').length > 0 )` to 0 and changed the position

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
$("[data-tag]").click(function() {
    var toTag = $(this).attr('data-tag');       
    var content = $('[contenteditable]');
    content.html(content.html().replace(/<\/(.*?)>/g, '</' + toTag + '>'));
    content.html(content.html().replace(/<(.*?)>/g, '<' + toTag + '>'));

}); 

<div id='ToP' data-tag="p">p</div>
<div id='ToH' data-tag="h1">h1</div>

<div contenteditable>
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9z5r49j/2/

Comment: the user must be able to choose what parts are h1 and what parts are p.